# WPF cut, copy, paste functionality on a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a canvas on which you can add UserControls (consists of images and textboxes)

Im trying to implement cut, copy, paste functionality on these UserControls, so the context menu is attatched to a UserControl which deals with images for example. A user right clicks here and from the context menu picks copy for instance how would I then go about implementing so they can paste this on to the canvas.

Can anyone point me in the right direction...

Comment: Are you using MVVM pattern ?

Comment: Im not, that is I dont know what that is. I've just started with c# and .net. By MVVM do you mean model view view model?

Comment: @kev3kev3 Yes, that is what MVVM stands for.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done with RoutedCommands. A full overview is at MSDN: [Commanding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx)

The short version is this: when a *command source* (i.e. a menu item) wants to execute a command, an event is raised. That event is handled by the nearest *command binding*. Cut/copy/paste commands are already included with WPF, and certain elements (namely, text boxes) already include command bindings for them.

You can define a menu item like this:

```
<MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy" />
```

And add a command binding to the UserControl like this:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Copy"
                    Executed="Copy_Executed" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

And define the `Copy_Executed` method with the [ExecutedRoutedEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.executedroutedeventhandler.aspx) signature in the UserControl's code-behind.

Then of course do the same thing for `ApplicationCommands.Paste` within the canvas.

It's up to you whether you want to handle the data within your own application, or use the clipboard. If you're working with images, WPF has a [Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Clipboard.aspx) class which can work with [BitmapSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx) objects (if you have an `Image` element, chances are its `Source` is already a `BitmapSource`).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, a well designed MVVM application can make copy/paste of user controls much simpler since it will turn to serialize/deserialize CLR objects to Clipboard. WPF will handle user control creation by itself after deserialization.

If your application does not implement MVVM. You can use XamlWriter/XamlReader to save user controls to XAML and recreate them by yourself. An example:

```
        StringBuilder outstr = new StringBuilder();

        //this code need for right XML fomating 
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.Indent = true;
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        XamlDesignerSerializationManager dsm =
          new XamlDesignerSerializationManager(XmlWriter.Create(outstr, settings));
        //this string need for turning on expression saving mode 
        dsm.XamlWriterMode = XamlWriterMode.Expression;
        XamlWriter.Save(control, dsm);

        //Read control from XAML
        var frameObject = XamlReader.Parse(outstr.ToString()) as UserControl;
        if (frameObject != null)
            stackPanel.Children.Add(frameObject);
```

For the part of how to put the XAML string or serialized stream into Clipboard, you can refer to MSDN.

Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind the command (as [@nmclean explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17816215/24874)) from code, you can use:

```
CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(
    ApplicationCommands.Copy,
    (sender, args) => { /* logic here */ }));
```